# how to use save wav files to current subdirectory in matlab?

Tags: matlab

My current directory is under C, for example, "C:\xxx\"

Now, I want to export my processed wav files to a subfolder in my current directory, for example, "\wav_results\".

What I have done is declaring a filepath variable:

```
wav_dir = '\wav_results\';
wavwrite(...., [wav_dir wav_name]) %wav_name is the name of the wav file
```

The error says no such file or directory. I do not want to use the full directory path for wav_dir because I need to move this script from place to place. Anyone has good suggestion?

Thanks~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [mkdir](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/mkdir.html) before you call wavwrite:

```
wav_dir = '\wav_results\'; %'
if not(exist('testresults','dir'))
    mkdir(wav_dir);
end
wavwrite(...., [wav_dir wav_name])
```

Comment: but, what if I need to append more files to that folder? I do not want to recreate the folder again.

Comment: That's what the `if not(exist(...))` line is for. It will only make the directory if it doesn't already exist.